# Transform coordinates from NOAA

Tags: r, coordinate-system, noaa

I use data from [NOAA](ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/noaa/ish-format-document.pdf) for some analysis in R and I want to transform coordinates to EPSG:54004 or something useful.

There is something what they write about their coordinates.

```
...    
POS: 29-34 
 GEOPHYSICAL-POINT-OBSERVATION latitude coordinate 
 The latitude coordinate of a GEOPHYSICAL-POINT-OBSERVATION where southern 
 hemisphere is negative. 
 MIN: -90000 MAX: +90000 
 UNITS: Angular Degrees 
 SCALING FACTOR: 1000 
 DOM: A general domain comprised of the numeric characters (0-9), a plus 
 sign (+), and a minus sign (-). 
 +99999 = Missing 

POS: 35-41 
 GEOPHYSICAL-POINT-OBSERVATION longitude coordinate 
 The longitude coordinate of a GEOPHYSICAL-POINT-OBSERVATION where values west from 
 000000 to 179999 are signed negative. 
 MIN: -179999 MAX: +180000 UNITS: Angular Degrees 
 SCALING FACTOR: 1000 
 DOM: A general domain comprised of the numeric characters (0-9), a plus 
 sign (+), and a minus sign (-). 
 +999999 = Missing
...
```

And my problem is, that I can't transform this coodrinates correctly. I use this R command:

```
    sc <- cbind(st$LAT, st$LON)
    ptransform(sc/180*pi, 
            '+proj=latlong +ellps=sphere',
            '+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs')
```

But coordinates are somehow wrong as you can see. The points should be in borders because they are meteostations from this countries. [image: Map with points].

Comment: Which coordinate system (EPSG code) would you like to transform to? If you are familiar with python, I can post a script that does that in a few lines of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, it was in input to ***ptransform*** function in R.
Instead `sc <- cbind(st$LAT, st$LON)` I have to use `sc <- cbind(st$LON, st$LAT)`. Then as you say I have to use EPSG:4326 as input CRS and EPSG:3857 as destination CRS. And the transformation with this command.

```
    tr <- ptransform(sc/180*pi, 
            '+proj=longlat',
            '+proj=merc')
```

[image: Correct transformation]

Answer (score 0):

In Python using pyproj, this is very simple:

```
import pyproj

def transform(epsg_in, epsg_out, x_in, y_in):
    # define source and destination coordinate systems based on the ESPG code
    srcProj = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:%i' % epsg_in, preserve_units=True)
    dstProj = pyproj.Proj(init='epsg:%i' % epsg_out, preserve_units=True)

    # perform the transformation
    x_out,y_out = pyproj.transform(srcProj, dstProj, x_in, y_in)
    print '(%.5f, %.5f) EPSG: %i => (%.5f, %.5f) EPSG: %i' % (x_in, y_in, epsg_in, x_out, y_out, epsg_out)
    return x_out, y_out

transform(**{
    "epsg_in" : 4326,
    "epsg_out" : 3912, 
    "x_in" : 14.5,
    "y_in" : 46.05
})
```

You only need to know epsg codes and input coordinates.