# Transform WGS84 coordinates to XY in R

Tags: r, coordinates, coordinate-system

I have a set of coordinates obtained from GPS signals in decimal degrees. These are apparently captured in WGS84 datum. I want to convert these into X and Y. below is a subset.

```
lon         lat
33.9500167  35.14637
33.94996    35.1463433
33.94999    35.14632
33.9500633  35.1462667
33.9500633  35.1463
33.9500467  35.1462467
33.95004    35.1463333
33.9499167  35.1463533
33.94975    35.1464233
33.94981    35.1464533
33.9500433  35.1463167
```

I want to do this probably in R as I do have signals from a few different receivers ending up with thousands of points. I need to get this X,Y values as I want to use it elsewhere in R that does not accept lon/lat cords.

Comment: [Relevant Math Stack Exchange Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185408/converting-from-longitude-latitude-to-cartesian-coordinates) 

Main takeway: Be careful homebrewing these solutions, find a library that exists ready.

Comment: you 'll need a map projection, UTM for example. Don't know how to do this in R, but may this is a starting point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18639967/converting-latitude-and-longitude-points-to-utm

Comment: I suppose leaflet for R converts lat/long to webmercator x/y somewhere, http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html

Answer (score 7):

Assuming your coordinates are offshore to Cyprus, UTM 36N EPSG:32636 is a good destination coordinate system. Otherwise, you might have swapped longitude and latitude, or missed negative signs for South and West coordinates.

[Transform coordinates from NOAA](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95127/transform-coordinates-from-noaa?rq=1) and [Transforming coordinates from WGS84 to Gauss-Krüger 5](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169876/transforming-coordinates-from-wgs84-to-gauss-kr%C3%BCger-5?rq=1) describe how to transform coordinates in R using [proj4::ptransform](https://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/proj4/transform.html) or [rgdal::spTransform](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgdal/versions/1.1-10/topics/spTransform-methods).

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30429384/how-to-transform-longitude-latitude-degree-to-utm-r-rgdal-sp